# How to load RGBA image in OpenCV faster?

Tags: java, kotlin, opencv

I'm loading ARGB image in OpenCV 4.7.0 from Kotlin like this:

```
private fun loadImageFromRawData(data: ByteArray, width: Int, height: Int): Mat {
    val mat = Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4)
    mat.put(0, 0, data)

    return mat
}
```

It works and takes 2-3 ms. But because OpenCV works with BGR, I have to convert it:

```
private fun loadImageFromRawData(data: ByteArray, width: Int, height: Int): Mat {
    val mat = Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4)
    mat.put(0, 0, data)
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)

    return mat
}
```

And after that method call takes around 13 ms, so the conversion takes around 10 ms.

I've also created a method that works 2 times faster (around 5 ms):

```
private fun convertRgbaToBgra(data: ByteArray) {
    for (i in data.indices step BYTES_PER_PIXEL) {
        val rComponentIndex = i + R_COMPONENT_INDEX
        val bComponentIndex = i + B_COMPONENT_INDEX

        val colorByte = data[rComponentIndex]
        data[rComponentIndex] = data[bComponentIndex]
        data[bComponentIndex] = colorByte
    }
}
```

Image size is around 1080x1920, Ubuntu 22.04, Java 19, Xeon E5-2696 (22 cores), 64 GB of RAM.

Is it possible to somehow speed it up?

Comment: The conversion BGR->RGB is very simple - swap channels 1 and 3 for each pixel. You could write it yourself with multiple threads to possibly speed it up (since each pixel is independent, it's easy to parallelize).

Comment: I haven't used OpenCV, but you could try reading bytes from the array and writing them to another byte array - if you're working with ARGB then you'd skip the A, store the R G and B (or maybe just the R and G and write the B directly) and write them to your temp array. And just repeat for the whole array. I'm not sure how fast it will be in comparison, but I think memory allocation is the slowest part, so if you have a consistent image size you could allocate your BGR array once and reuse it

Comment: your allocation is suspect. you are dealing with RGB/BGR, which are **three-channel**, not four-channel. cvtColor will reallocate the Mat. -- applying RGB2BGR on 4-channel data will potentially fail. neither source nor destination code describe a 4-channel layout. -- cvtColor likely is heavily optimized already. you should consider how you can avoid this operation or have the data generated to be suitable. why ***specifically*** do you think you need to convert color spaces?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz actually is 4-bytes (with alpha channel), but I've decided to simplify the question. I'm converting the color space because I also need to compress it to JPEG or PNG after all operations, and the resulting image obviously has wrong colors because OpenCV thinks that it's BGR

Comment: what's the source of "raw data"? why do you not use 4-channel color conversion codes? cvtColor has conversion codes for color + alpha channel

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the source is the Android's MediaProjection screen capture. "why do you not use 4-channel color conversion codes" - because I've misunderstood the codes. I've updated the answer (fixed code to the correct one, it gives the same performance)

Comment: What do you intend to do with the result? It's mostly things from `imgcodecs`, `videoio` and `highgui` modules (and of course `cvtColor`) that actually care about the input being BGR(A).

Comment: OP said: storing the data in a file. if that's done with imwrite(), the conversion would be required. if done with system APIs (android isn't dumb, can do video encoding/compression too), then not.